Calculating the unvalid states of several machines
Assume we have a 2-sided machine, which the states of it can be described via a boolean vector. If all elements of this boolean vector is 0 or 1, then it is an unvalid state:
States:
0 0    unvalid
0 1    valid
1 0    valid
1 0    unvalid

When we consider two 2-sided machines, then the total states would be unvalid if any of the machine states are unvalid like following:
States:
0 0 | 0 0    unvalid
0 0 | 0 1    unvalid
0 0 | 1 0    unvalid
0 0 | 1 1    unvalid
0 1 | 0 0    unvalid
0 1 | 0 1    valid
0 1 | 1 0    valid
0 1 | 1 1    unvalid
1 0 | 0 0    unvalid
1 0 | 0 1    valid
1 0 | 1 0    valid
1 0 | 1 1    unvalid
1 1 | 0 0    unvalid
1 1 | 0 1    unvalid
1 1 | 1 0    unvalid
1 1 | 1 1    unvalid

How would we calculate for n amount of m-sided machines, the total amount of unvalid and valid states?

the minimum side of a machine is 2.
m does not always a constant, so for example I want to be able to also calculate one 2-sided, one 3-sided, and one 4-sided machine (example state: [1, 0 | 0, 0, 1 | 1, 1, 0, 1]).

PS: I suspect the result would be (2^2-2) * (2^3-2) * (2^4-2), is it correct?

Let us start with the case where each machine is $m$-sided (where $m$ is contant). We then have that we need each of the machine to be valid. For each machine there are $2^m$ states, of which 2 states are invalid. Hence, there are $2^m-2$ valid states. We can then multiply all of these together to get $(2^m-2)^n$ valid states. In your second example, where $m=n=2$, you showed there are 4 valid states which matches the equation.
Now, suppose we have $n$ machines, where the $k$th machine is $m_k$-sided. Then we can generalize our above formula to see the $k$th machine has $2^{m_k}-2$ valid states. To find the total number of valid states we must multiply the number of valid states for each machine hence getting:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^n (2^{m_k}-2) $$
We can verify this when $m_i = m_j = m$ for all valid $i$ and $j$, this turns into the equation we got from the first part.
